# Merging APFS Containers using the Disk Utility Application

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I recently deleted my dual boot from my mac, but I am now left with two partitions that I can't figure out how to merge. I would like it to be normal again with just one container: Macintosh HD. I'm running MacOS Mojave.

Here is my current situation as shown in the "Disk Utility" application and the output from the `diskutil list` command.

[image: Disk Utility application]

[image: diskutil list results]

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do this in the GUI, you can do advanced hard disk editing with [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/hdm-mac/).
Not "merge" merging the containers, but most likely you'll need to remove a containter and then resize main container where the macOS resides. It can be done on the fly - i.e. you can edit the same partition/container from which you booted the system. Paragon Hard Disk Manager has 10 day trial period, during which you can use all its functions.

Answer (score 1):

The Disk Utility application probably can not be use to fix your Mac. Below is a alternate procedure.

1. Start up the Mac from macOS Recovery over the Internet by restarting and immediately pressing and holding the the key combination Option-⌘-R.
2. From the menu bar, select to open a Terminal application window.
3. Enter the following command to get the GUID Partition Table (GPT) entries.

   ```
   gpt -r show disk0
   ```

   An example output is shown below.

   ```
   $ gpt -r show disk0
         start       size  index  contents
             0          1         PMBR
             1          1         Pri GPT header
             2         32         Pri GPT table
            34          6         
            40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
        409640   97656248      2  GPT part - FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
      98065888        544         
      98066432   97245184      3  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
     195311616        891         
     195312507         32         Sec GPT table
     195312539          1         Sec GPT header
   ```
4. Enter the command given below to change the GPT.

   ```
   gpt -f remove -i 3 disk0
   gpt -f remove -i 2 disk0
   gpt -f add -i 2 -b  <start> -s <size> -t apfs disk0
   ```

   Where `<start>` and `<size>` are integers taken from the row with index equal to 2 in the table shown in step 2. An example is shown below.

   ```
   $ gpt -f remove -i 3 disk0
   disk0s3 removed
   $ gpt -f remove -i 2 disk0
   disk0s2 removed
   $ gpt -f add -i 2 -b  409640 -s 97656248 -t apfs disk0  
   disk0s2 added
   ```

   **You will need to replace `409640` and `97656248` with the values shown in your GPT table.**
5. Restart the Mac back to macOS Mojave.
6. Enter the command given below in a Terminal application window to reclaim the free space.

   ```
   sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
   ```